# How can i get Kendo edit button val

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid with edit button inside, I don't know how can I get the id of it because I need the val,in the code below I already have written codes for Edit so how can I add more function to edit?

```
       $("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
                            //   debugger;

                            dataSource: dataSource,
                            scrollable: false,
                            toolbar: ["create"],

                            columns: [
                                     { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                     { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', },//editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor,
                                     { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px' },
                                     { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', editor: deviceTypesList },
                                     { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                                     { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                                     { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                                     { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                                     { field: 'TurbineId', title: 'TurbineId', width: '120px', hidden: true },
                                     { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px', hidden: true },
                                     { field: 'ModelProducer', title: 'Producer/Model', hidden: true, editor: modelProducer },
                                     { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;" }
                                     ],
        //                              {
        //                                  command: [
        //{
        //    name: "Edit",
        //    click: function (e) {
        //        temp = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //get the row

        //    }
        //}
        //                                  ]
        //                              }


                            editable: "popup",                                            
                            edit: 
                                function (e) {                                                                 
                                e.container.find("label[for='device_id']").parent().hide();
                                e.container.find("div[data-container-for='device_id']").hide();

                            }


                        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I add more function to edit", you mean more functionality when the button is clicked or?

Comment: @Adriani6  yeas I want to as soon as edit button clicked{do.....}

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide further information of how and when you want to get the button, I have created a demo where you can get the button reference when the edit button is clicked. The event is something like:

```
edit: function(e) {
    var $currentButton = $(this.tbody).find('tr[data-uid="' + e.model.uid + '"] td:last .k-button');
};
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oTatO)

Comment: thanks for the demo,but now how can I find if this edit button is clicked?

Comment: @mrslt it only triggers when the button is clicked anyway.

Comment: I updated my question up there,please take a look at the edit part,i already have some tags there,possible also to add the function you wrote also? @DontVoteMeDown

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click event callback when setting up the kendoGrid(). Inside the javascript function that you call you can get access to the grid's dataItem (which will contain all of the data used by the dataSource).

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [ { command: [ { name: "Edit", click: "onClickFunc" ] } ]
});

function onClickFunc(e) {
    var grid = $("#turbingrid").getKendoGrid();
    var data = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var deviceId = dataItem.device_id; // or whatever other property
}
```

I'm assuming you are trying to get a value from you dataSource row that the command button was clicked on.